# Nested Stored Procedure Connections

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transaction, connections, connection-pooling

I have a Stored procedure that simply looks for Imported files through a set of other processes. The main SP runs every 5 mins and looks for new files in a directory and imports them into a staging table if there is a newer file.

At this point, if it does import a newly added file, there is another accompanying SP that ETL's the records from staging into another production DB. The ETL (`EXEC dbo.ETL`) is happening inside the monitoring SP that runs every 5 minutes.

My main question is, can I have the ETL stored Procedure run independently of the monitoring SP?
If an ETL SP takes longer than 5 mins, when the monitoring SP is called again, will it use another connection if the last call 5 mins ago is still running the ETL procedure?

IOW, I want to run a SP (SP #1) every 5 mins that calls other SPs (that may take more or less than 5 mins) without interrupting SP #1

Comment: You WILL need a way to test this situation regardless of how you want things to work. Guessing is not an effective path. But you have a single staging table, correct? What will happen when your import process starts while your ETL process is still using the staging table? Think carefully about this approach.

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to build a simple SSIS package that runs the stored procedure you need; then call it from tsql in this way:

```
declare @execution_id bigint
 exec ssisdb.catalog.create_execution 
  @folder_name = 'folder'
 ,@project_name = 'project_name'
 ,@package_name = 'run_sp.dtsx'
 ,@execution_id = @execution_id output

 exec ssisdb.catalog.start_execution @execution_id
```

This call is asyncronous by default

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking of you can call some other stored procedure asynchronously? No, not natively, so to speak. We usually have two options for this:

Execute an Agent job, using sp_start_job. Note that an agent job doesn't have parameters so if you want to pass data into this job, so to speak, you can use a table as a communication mechanism. Note that if the ETL is running (through a started Agent job) and your monitoring proc tries to start it again, then it won't be started. Agent will not start a job if it's already running.

Use Service Broker. This is queuing in SQL Server, so your "outer" proc can send a message to a queue, and you can have either a polling mechanism to poll the queue or activation (Service Broker kicks off something when a message is received).

Or did you mean something different? If so, please clarify. Your last sentence is a bit confusing since you essentially say that you want to run sp #1 without interrupting sp #1.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Sorry about my last sentence being confusing. Since a SQL Agent Job cannot be ran if its already running, I will look into other solutions. Thank you for your response